# Copy text and keep format from <pre> tag (ReactJS)

Tags: html, css, reactjs, pre

Please view my CodeSandbox [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/peaceful-shadow-0wzrvy).

For the CodeSandbox, I manually select the text like so:

[image]

Then, I paste it into a notepad, and this is what that notepad looks like. The line breaks are maintained, and this is exactly what I need:

[image]

However, when I use the same code in my local environment, select the text from the localhost and paste it into a notepad, I get this. For some reason, the text is being displayed as one string, without the indenting that I'd like in the previous picture.

[image]

Does anyone have any suggestions to get the `<pre>` tag indenting to show when I copy and paste the code locally?

**Goal:** To be able to manually select the text in my local div, and paste into a notepad with the same formatting from the UI.